# Echo last record from database using Kohana

Tags: php, mysql, sql, kohana

I know this is a basic question but i can't work out how i can amend my query to just display the last record inserted to that table.  If i was using `mysqli_query` i would have something like(not perfect as just a quick example):

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT `fname`,`lname`,`postcode`,`email` FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;)
                VALUES (:fname, :lname, :postcode, :email)');   
$stmt->execute();
$result=mysqli_query($stmt);
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>First Name</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

In Kohana I currently have the following which is working fine except it is displaying all users and I just want the last record/user inserted to be displayed, how can I implement the query from the first(mysqli) bit of code to the second(Kohana)

```
$results = DB::select('fname', 'lname', 'postcode', 'email')->from('mytable')->execute();
$users = $results->as_array();
foreach($users as $user)
{
echo 'First Name: '.$user['fname'];
echo 'Last Name: '.$user['lname'];
echo 'Postcode: '.$user['postcode'];
echo 'Email: '.$user['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, why not implement them using the query builder's methods [`order_by()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select#order_by) and [`limit()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Database_Query_Builder_Select#limit)?

```
$results = DB::select('fname', 'lname', 'postcode', 'email')->from('mytable')
  ->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->execute();
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks, I wasn't sure how you would set the `order_by()` and `limit()` correctly, embarrassingly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Or if using ORM

```
ORM::factory('table')->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->find();
```